# Providing the theoretical steps to prove the formula for the confidence interval in simple linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

This is the exact question

Explain from first principles the theoretical steps required to prove the formula for the confidence interval for the mean response in the simple linear regression model corresponding to a value $x_0$ of the predictor. You may assume without proof that $\operatorname{cov}\left(\overline y, \widehat b\right) =0.$

I don't really understand the question because it's not asking me to prove anything just describe what I'd do if I was trying to prove it, can somebody help me out?

Comment: I don't think there's any substantial difference in this context between proving the result and explaining what you would do to prove the result.

Comment: The center of the confidence interval is the fitted value $\widehat y = \overline y + \widehat b(x_0 - \overline x). \qquad$

Comment: You'll have a t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the sample size. The unbiased estimator of the error variance $\sigma^2$ is $\widehat\sigma^2 = \dfrac 1 {n-2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \widehat y_i)^2.$ You have $$ \frac{(n-2)\widehat\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2} $$ and that is independent of $\widehat y,$ which is normally distributed.

Comment: Is there much to do from there? My friend has 2 massive pages of writing I'm just really confused by the question

Comment: Actually writing up the whole thing takes involves more than what appears above; these are just some central ideas. One would hope to write it in a way that's not confusing, though. Are you using matrix algebra? $\qquad$

Comment: Not using matrix algebra no, I have some work for it now but no idea if what I'm doing is right

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short version of the answer. You have
$$
Y_i \sim N(a+ bx_i, \sigma^2) \quad\text{for } i = 1,\ldots, n,
$$
i.e. the expected value of $Y_i$ given the value of $x_i$ is $a+bx_i,$ and the error has variance $\sigma^2.$

Thus $Y_i$ is treated as random and $x_i$ is not. The justification for not treating $x_i$ as random is often (not always) that one speaks of the *conditional* distribution of $Y_i$ *given* $x_i.$

Let $\overline x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$ and $\overline Y = (Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)/n.$ Then the least-squares estimates of $b$ and $a$ are
$$
\widehat{\,b\,} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)(Y_i - \overline Y)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)^2}, \qquad \widehat a = \overline Y - \widehat b\overline x.
$$
Then $\widehat a$ and $\widehat {\,b\,}$ are random whereas $a$ and $b$ are not.
Although we have
$$
\frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - (a+bx_i))^2 \sim \chi^2_n,
$$
we have
$$
\frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - (\widehat a+\widehat{\,b\,}x_i))^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-2}. \tag 1
$$
Just why $(1)$ has that distribution is something I would normally explain with matrix algebra.

Now notice that
$$
\widehat a + \widehat{\,b\,}x_i = \overline Y + \widehat{\,b\,} (x_i - \overline x) \sim N( a+bx_i,\,\underbrace{\operatorname{var}(\,\overline Y\,) + \operatorname{var}(\,\widehat{\,b\,}\,) (x_i-\overline x)^2\,}_{\text{no covariance term}} \,). \tag 2
$$
There is no covariance term because of the fact mentioned in the question.

The one additional fact needed is that the quantities mentioned in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are independent.

Then go back to the fact that $\dfrac Z {\chi_{n-2}/\sqrt{n-2}}$ has a t-distribution and do a bunch of routine algebra.